# Scipy.io savemat / loadmat with list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to create a list of lists and add it to a dictionary key and then save the dictionary as a `.mat` file. My code looks like this:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
dic = {"X": [[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[6,7,8,9],[1]]}
savemat('Test.mat', mdict=dic)
```

When I load the `.mat` file with `loadmat` and print `dic['X']`; the output should be `[[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[6,7,8,9],[1]]`. Instead I'm getting this:

```
[[array([[1, 2, 3]]) array([[1, 2, 4]]) array([[6, 7, 8, 9]]) array([[1]])]]
```

My code snippet for loading and restoring `dic`:

```
X = loadmat("Test.mat")
print(X['X'])
```

How do I store the original list into `.mat` file?

Comment: Use `pickle` if you want save Python structures like dictionaries and lists.  Or JSON. But why are you using `numpy` and `scipy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that your library does not work well with lists of lists, and especially *where the sublists have different lengths*. You should check if this is indeed the case.

As per the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html), `scipy.io.savemat` is designed for a dictionary of arrays, which is not what you have provided:

> Save a dictionary of names and arrays into a MATLAB-style .mat file.
>
> This saves the array objects in the given dictionary to a MATLAB-
>   style .mat file.

What you can do is restructure your data:

```
dic = {"A": np.array([1, 2, 3]),
       "B": np.array([1, 2, 4]),
       "C": np.array([6, 7, 8, 9]),
       "D": np.array([1])}
```

Remember that a `numpy` array with rows of different length will become `dtype=Object` and virtually unusable for most vectorised functions. It probably won't work well with `scipy` either.

---

A painful solution is to perform the conversion when you load the data again:

```
import numpy as np
from operator import itemgetter

lst = [[np.array([[1, 2, 3]]), np.array([[1, 2, 4]]),
        np.array([[6, 7, 8, 9]]), np.array([[1]])]]

res = list(map(list, (map(itemgetter(0), map(list, lst[0])))))

[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [6, 7, 8, 9], [1]]
```

---

There is no native function composition in Python, but the above logic can be made more readable with 3rd party library `toolz`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from toolz import compose

res = list(map(compose(list, itemgetter(0), list), lst[0]))
```